# how to know which image was clicked

Tags: javascript, php

I have the following php code:

```
session_start();
    include "config.php";
    $sql="SELECT Photoid FROM photos";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if($result->num_rows > 0){
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {   

            $name=$row["Photoid"];

            echo '<img src="'.$name.'" / width="200px" height="200px"       onclick="myFunction()">'; 


        }
    }else{
        echo "0 results";
    }
$conn->close();
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() {
        location.href = 'photo-page.php';
    }
</script>
```

With which i display some photos that i get from a database and then i make them clickable so i can be transferred to another page "photo-page.php".
What i want to do is to know which of those photos that i display has been clicked in order to know which one i should display on  the photo-page.

Comment: Add the variable `name` as a parameter in your function.

Comment: Through the param of myFunction, you receive an event. You can access `event.target` to check wich one is clicked

Comment: You can use anchor tag instead of javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
echo '<img src="'.$name.'" / width="200px" height="200px" onclick="myFunction()">';
```

To

```
echo '<img src="'.$name.'" / width="200px" height="200px"       onclick="myFunction('.$name.')">'
```

And

```
function myFunction(name) 
{
   alert(name);
   //  location.href = 'photo-page.php';
}
```

Comment: can you indent rather than ticking? it also helps for syntax highlighting should there be any syntax errors. Edit: thanks ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Sure boss

Comment: @Fred-ii- LOl then "Sure seneor"

Comment: @greg Glad it helped you... :)

Answer (score 0):

Use HTML anchors and append GET data:

```php
<?php
// index.php
// ...
echo '<a href="photo-page.php?img-name='.$name.'">';
echo '<img src="'.$name.'" width="200px" height="200px">'; 
echo '</a>';
// ...
?>
```

In `photo-page.php`, you can retrieve the name of the image via the `$_GET` variable:

```php
<?php
// photo-page.php
// ...
if (isset($_GET['img-name'])) {
  $imageName = $_GET['img-name'];
  // display the image in its full size
  echo '<img src="'.$imageName.'">';
}
// ...
?>
```